# Empty parameters in codeigniter url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have a controller which takes 4 parameters. Sometimes parameters can be empty. Standard url is like **review/fetch_reviews/10/uk/topcomments/1234**
where 10 represents count for paging.If that parameter is blank then url becomes **review/fetch_reviews//uk//** and my sql query becomes **select * from table limit uk,10**.
I even set default value for parameters as bellow

```
function fetch_reviews($page="10",$banktype="",$country="",$filter=""){
```

how to handle this? Itried URI routing but t doesnt work.

Comment: You can pass // it self to pass empty parameted e.g. site.com/class/function/papra1/para2//para4, Here para 3 is missing;  however you have to set para3 as optional parameter in function like para3=''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your functional parameter as optional and pass this optional value like

Url:

`site.com/class/myfunction/para1/null/para3`

and function

`public function myfunction($para1,$para2="null",para3)
{
   //function body
}`

Comment: Thannks for the reply. I did that but the whats's happening is, insted of considering it as a null its assumes that para2 is passed at place of para1, So my query "limit 10,10" becomes "limit uk,10"

Comment: Uhh quite strange issue class/myfunction//undefined// this works fine, but class/myfunction//retail// throws error :D :D So i added condition if($currpage == "undefined" || !is_numeric($currpage)) $currpage = 0; Now it worked. Thanks chintan for clue.